# Handling dynamic controls from master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have a asp:placeholder in master page. From content page (in page_init) I am dynamically creating drop downs and adding to the asp: placeholder in master page. How do I access these dynamically created controls by id?

I tried this

```
 Dim Outer_CP As ContentPlaceHolder Outer_CP = TryCast(Me.Master.Master.FindControl("MyContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)

 Dim mydropdownsAs PlaceHolder = TryCast(Outer_CP.FindControl("mydropdownsAs "), PlaceHolder)

 Dim ddlControl As DropDownList = CType(mydropdownsAs .FindControl(idName), DropDownList)
```

Comment: how you create these dynamic controls? are you sure about the control's ids? maybe the control ids are dynamic so they differ from the actual id you set in the code?

Comment: yes. The controls ids are also dynamic. When I saw then in view source I see that they are prefixed with "myContent" always. Also when I created them I gave an ID name. And that is now prefixed with a string so it appears like.. MyContent_ddl123

Comment: They are appearing on screen fine. but my problem is ..I have a btn and when that is clicked I need the selected value of that dropdown. when the dropdown is selected , selected index changed event is firing and I can take the value from there. But If the user does not select any any value from dropdown then I need to take the default value of that drop down...I have a prob here as I am unable to find the dropdown I want..